# How to learn if my branch is behind the remote repository in Git using command line?

Tags: git

What is the command that I should use in Windows to learn if I am behind the repository?

Comment: @pktangyue Does not show the information I need.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: Only what branch I am currently on and that my files are not staged for commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply type

```
git status
```

It will tell you how many commits ahead you are:

[image: ahead by one commit]

For "behind", you have to do

```
git fetch
```

and then a `git status`:

[image]

Comment: It does not? It only tells what branch I am currently on and that my changes are not staged for commit.

Comment: @KorayTugay That's because you don't have any commit difference. Try commiting a minor change (like a space) and rerun `git status`. It will tell you you are "ahead of master by 1 commit". Look at my edit (image)

Comment: I am not ahead, I am behind and I want to see that I am behind.

Comment: @KorayTugay You are right. You have to `fetch` the changes before the `git status`: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to fetch new references from the repository:

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
```

Then using

```
git status
```

will tell you how many commits you are behind.

Comment: The name of your remote repository, likely `origin`.

Comment: Reading the comments clarifying the question, the `git fetch` command is not necessary. I understood it as the question whether your local clone is behind a remote repository.

Comment: Question is, behind *what*? Reading your [last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291598/how-to-learn-if-my-branch-is-behind-the-remote-repository-in-git-using-command-l/15291669?noredirect=1#comment21578530_15291598) it seems like you want to see what branch you are on and which files are not committed. For that you certainly don't need the remote information, only when you are interested in whether there have been commits pushed to the remote by other people you need it.

Comment: No, I want to see if I am behind the repository. Your link to my last comment does not work.

Comment: Rats :-) I tried it, but apparently links to comments are not persistent.